# LC-3, loading an address value vs. loading the contents of that address

Tags: lc3

I need to write a TRAP function that prompts the user for 2 16-bit memory addresses, then displays the range of those 2 addresses as well as their contents.  I've got all the code written to do the displaying work, my problem is that while I can load a value into a register, I can't figure out how to treat that value as an address.  Example: User has entered xAAAA and xAAAD.  I need to output something like:

```
    LOCATION:         CONTENTS:
    xAAAA             xFF07
    xAAAB             x123A
    xAAAC             x8CD2
    xAAAD             x4321
```

I can print the location and increment it in a loop just fine, but treating the value as an address instead of a value escapes me.  If I use

```
    LEA R0, VALUE1
```

I'll just get the address where VALUE1 is stored, and if I use

```
    LD R0, VALUE1
```

I'll just get the value. What I'm trying to do is have VALUE1 describe an address. Can anyone help point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the instruction LDI.

The syntax is: `LDI destination_register, source_offset`

What it does is to go to the label (which translates to offset in the assembly process) and use it's value as a pointer to the required data, and then put the data in the register.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=359TeV9UvM8) is a video explaining that instruction.